# Can't call SonarQube from Jenkins job

Tags: java, docker, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm using the SonarQube Docker image in my project:

```
docker run --name sonarqube --detach \
  --network cicd \
  --publish 9000:9000 \
  sonarqube:7.9.4-community
```

On the same network (`cicd`) I have a running Jenkins (within Docker) as well. I configured my Jenkins job to call SonarQube in a step:

```
mvn sonar:sonar \
    -Dsonar.projectKey=cicd \
    -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube:9000 \
    -Dsonar.login=f529a61c801dfe9e1e848a74f543ea129e4bdfc1
```

but I get an error message:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project ci-cd-demo: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:85)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:56)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:42)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles(JarDownloader.java:58)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:53)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: sonarqube: Name does not resolve
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Dns.lambda$static$0(Dns.java:39)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:135)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:187)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:113)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:98)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39)
    ... 32 more
```

What's weird is that `sonarqube` exists, if I log into any of my containers and I try to `curl http://sonarqube:9000` I get a result back. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: I checked the docker network with `docker network inspect cicd` and if I use the IP address of `sonarqube` it starts to work, but I'd like to keep using the host instead.

Comment: It is not related to sonarqube integration. It is related sonar-maven-plugin that you have defined in pom.xml or you have missed to add the plugin dependency in pom.xml

Comment: Why would it say `sonarqube: Name does not resolve` if it was not about host resolution?

Comment: Ohh...I missed the error. Let me check once again.

Comment: Yeah...it is very weird, I haven't found a solution to this yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the Jenkins host in the sonar.properties file under `http.nonProxyHost`

We have also faced the similar issue as our Jenkins server is on RHEL machine, so we added the Jenkins host in `http.nonProxyHost` of sonar.properties file and Jenkins to call sonarqube worked.

Follow this two post for more details:

1. https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/150
2. https://community.sonarsource.com/t/http-nonproxyhosts-has-no-effect-webhook-delivery-failing-ce-7-9-1-build-27448/17630

Hope this might resolve your issue.